# Installing a Reverse Osmosis (RO) system under sink, should the feed connection go after or before the dishwasher connection?

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink, p-trap, water-filtration

Not sure if it matters, but do I connect the RO systems feed water connection before or after the dishwasher feed water connection.

Also, where’s the best place to put the drain saddle?

[image: picture of sink plumbing]

Answer (score 1):

Are you feeding the RO system with hot water?  You should ideally feed the RO with cold and the dishwasher with hot, so the question of which one to connect first doesn't really come up often.

As for the drain saddle, locate it as high as possible and before the dishwasher drain connection so that the huge flood of dishwasher wastewater doesn't ever have a chance to try to enter the RO drain tube.

Comment: I just realized this question was over a year old, so probably a non-issue by now. :)

Comment: Yes, I was confused. The cold water connection was actually feeding the ice maker in my fridge. I ended up connecting the RO to the cold and then splitting the filtered output between the RO system and the ice maker (with a T connection.) I put the drain saddle after dishwasher drain, I hope it’s okay. The hole I drilled was only ¼” so it’s not big.

Answer (score 0):

It's all the same water so it doesn't matter.